# Force https:// for some URLs, and force www. on all

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I'm trying to set up an SSL for a site using Codeigniter.

I need to to force https:// on certain pages (such as login, basket etc).

What I have so far, which forces www. successfully, and removes the index.php from the URL for cleaner results with Codeigniter:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep your redirect rules before rewrite ones:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443 [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(login|basket|shop)
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Didn't seem to work. If I go to the login page without https:// at the start it still allows access to that page insecurely (without forcing https://)

Comment: You need to provide exact login URL for which you want `https`

Comment: It would just be mydomain.com/login

Comment: When you enter `http://domain.com/login` does the URL remain same? Not even `www` gets added?

Comment: What version of Apache you use? What happens when you use `https://www.domain.com/login`?

Comment: When I load by typing in the https:// it loads fine, but without https:// it doesn't then force or change the URL to https://, it just allows the page to load with http://

Comment: Try updated code and and do tell me which Apache version are you on?

Comment: That causes a redirect loop but the URL in the browser is https://. Apache version is 2.2.22